# Electron dialog.showOpenDialog not running callback

Tags: dialog, electron, filesystems

I have been trying to make a simple program to create and read files with Electron.
So far I have tried a lot and it seems the callback function I provide with the dialog.showOpenDialog is not being called.

```
    dialog.showOpenDialog( (filePaths) => {
        console.log('this callback is called');
        console.log(filePaths);
    });

    //Directly read a test file
    fs.readFile('readtest.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This is the code inside my read button handler.
The dialog opens and I choose a file and it simply does nothing. 
However the same file which I selected is read by the fs.readFile and displayed in the console.

It seems the callback is not getting called after I choose the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns a promise, so you can chain it with .then:

```
    dialog.showOpenDialog(null, options).then((filePaths) => {
    console.log('this callback is called');
    console.log(filePaths);
});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. I just realized that. Was following some old articles and they used callbacks. Went and checked the current documentation and saw that it returns a promise. So got it solved. Appreciate your help. :)